# using swedish letters ÖÄÅ with sort in batch

Tags: sorting, batch-file, non-ascii-characters

I need to sort a table of contents that contains Swedish letters in Batch.

I can echo them using (`chcp 65001`) at the top of my code.

Is there a way to to sort the list according to the swedish alphabetical order ?(something like `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` in bash)

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. I've fixed it using (chcp 1252) and changing the encoding of the input text file to (UTF-16 LE)